# (C# / VB.NET) Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape.AddComment - "NotImplementedException" when "Microsoft Office"-Version is newer than 2010

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-office, office-interop

The "Interop"-Interface for Office seems to have some problems interacting with "Microsoft Office" when the "Microsoft Office"-version is newer than 2010. When using the "AddComment"-Function in "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPont.Shapes" I get an "System.NotImplementedException".
In "Microsoft Office 2010" or older everything works fine.

**additional information:**

- I for myself have only a 2010-version of "Microsoft Office". The issue was reported by co-workers which have newer versions.
- The current version number of my "Interop.PowerPoint.dll" is "2.6.0.0".

**questions:**

- Is my "Interop.PowerPoint.dll" too old?
- What is the version number of the newest existing "Interop.PowerPoint.dll"?
- Is there any way to get the newest "Interop.PowerPoint.dll" even if I still have only a 2010-version of "Microsoft Office"?
- Can my "NotImplementedException" have some other causes?
- Is there any way to work around this Problem? I just want to make my program write comments into a "PowerPoint" file.

[image: MessageBox about Exception]

Comment: Are you using your own dll and copying to the output your dll or are you using the system dll of each user as framework?

Comment: In any case I would update the library

Comment: I'm afaid that how the current "Interop"-libraries came from are only co-workers knowing wich are not working for us anymore since years. But this is not a problem because perhaps I can easily get newer "Interop"-libraries by NuGet. Anyways me and my co-workers agreed to work arround the problem that is about writing comments into a PowerPoint-File when using newer "MS Office"-versions. We just write the data we need to write to another place. Anyways thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The interop assembly doesn't contain any sophisticated logic or implementation of the method. The goal of the interop assembly is to marshal your calls from a managed code to the unmanaged COM world. So, if the method fails the problem should be searched in the COM server implementation.

You can download PIAs [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=3508) or generate in Visual Studio on your own.

You may also find Office PIAs in the Visual Studio installation folder if Office extensibility feature was selected while installing it. Read more about that in the [Office primary interop assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2022) article.

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, these copies of the PIAs are installed to following shared locations on the development computer:

- `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\`
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\` - on 64-bit operating systems)